# Derivation of energy integral - harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am following the solution of the following problem on the topic of the energy integral of a surface.

> For a real-valued continuously differentiable function $u(x,y)$ on a closed domain $D$, the energy integral is defined as follows. $$E(u)=\iint_D \left( \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2\right) dxdy.$$ If on $B$, the boundary of $D$, the function $u$ achieves the specific values of some function $f$, how can $E(u)$ be minimized within $D$ over all functions $u$, given the described boundary-constraint?

Here is how the author goes about finding out how to minimize the energy integral.

> Suppose that the function $u_0$ produces this minimum: $$E(u_0)\leq E(u),\,\,\,\textrm{ for all functions }u\textrm{ with }u=f \textrm{ on } B$$
>   Let $v$ be any continuously differentiable function on $D$ that is zero on $B$. Then $u_0+\epsilon v$ equals $f$ on $B$ for any number $\epsilon$, and because $u_0$ has the minimum energy integral, $$\begin{align*}
> E(u_0)&\leq E(u_0+\epsilon v)\\
> &= E(u_0) + 2\epsilon \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dxdy + \epsilon^2 E(v)
> \end{align*}$$

The last part is what I don't understand. Where did that expansion of $E(u_0+\epsilon v)$ come from? Could anybody explain what each term in that expansion is there for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the simpler ($\LaTeX$-wise) notation

$u_{,x} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \tag{1}$

we have

$(u_0 + \epsilon v)_{,x} = u_{0,x} + \epsilon v_{,x}, \tag{2}$

whence

$((u_0 + \epsilon v)_{,x})^2 = (u_{0,x})^2 + 2\epsilon u_{0,x} v_{,x} + \epsilon^2 (v_{,x})^2; \tag{3}$

similarly

$((u_0 + \epsilon v)_{,y})^2 = (u_{0,y})^2 + 2 \epsilon u_{0,y} v_{,y} + \epsilon^2 (v_{,y})^2; \tag{4}$

when (3) and(4) are used in the expression for $E(u_0 + \epsilon v)$, the stated formula easily follows.

Hope this helps.  Good Yule Season,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***